# Django REST pagination relative URL instead of absolute URL in ListAPIView

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework

Django Rest Framework generic.ListAPIView sets next&prev parameters to absolute URLs. But I need to set them to relative URLs.

I need to return JSON as below

```
# {'count': 4, 'next': '?page=2', 'previous': None, 'results': [u'john', u'paul']}
```

not like this

```
# {'count': 4, 'next': 'http://testserver/foobar?page=2', 'previous': None, 'results': [u'john', u'paul']}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the implementation @iankit suggsted:

```
from rest_framework.utils.urls import remove_query_param, replace_query_param
class LeadListPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 15

    def get_next_link(self):
        if not self.page.has_next():
            return None
        url = self.request.get_full_path()
        page_number = self.page.next_page_number()
        return replace_query_param(url, self.page_query_param, page_number)

    def get_previous_link(self):
        if not self.page.has_previous():
            return None
        url = self.request.get_full_path()
        page_number = self.page.previous_page_number()
        if page_number == 1:
            return remove_query_param(url, self.page_query_param)
        return replace_query_param(url, self.page_query_param, page_number)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the new styles of Pagination, you will have to override get_next_link and get_previous_link methods in the pagination class.

In these methods, use get_full_path() instead of build_absolute_uri().

Although it is always better to be explicit and return absolute URLs in the response, yet there are times when you would want to return relative URI's.

Answer (score 0):

Your're going to have to overwrite `rest_framework.pagination.NextPageField.to_native()`. And use it in your own custom pagination serializer